# Calling multiple Blazor components with two binding

Tags: components, blazor, call

I have a blazor component:

```html
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using bullDocDBAcess
@using bullDocDBAcess.Models

@inject ITagData _db

@if(tags == null){
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}else{
        <input type="text" @bind=@tags data-role="tagsinput" />
        <input type="hidden" @onchange="onChange" value=@tags />
}


@code{
    private string tags = "";

    private List<TagModel> tagsList;

   
    private Task<IJSObjectReference> _module;
    private Task<IJSObjectReference> Module => _module ??= JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./components/tagsinput/tags_inputs_imports.js").AsTask();

    [Parameter]
    public int organizationId { get; set; } = 0;
    
    [Parameter]
    public int documentId { get; set; } = 0;
    
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Notification> OnTagsChange { get; set; }
    private void onChange(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        tags = (string) args.Value;
        OnTagsChange.InvokeAsync(new Notification(tags, documentId.ToString()));
       
    }    

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if(organizationId == 0){ //inserção
            tags = "";
        }else{
            tagsList = await _db.GetTagsFromDocument(organizationId, documentId);
            
            foreach (TagModel t in tagsList){
                if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(tags)){
                    tags += t.nome;
                }else{
                    tags += "," + t.nome;
                }
            }
          
        }
     
         var module = await Module;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("loadScripts");
        
        
    }   
  
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_module != null)
        {
            var module = await _module;
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the idea is to use a bootstrap input tag (called using jsinterop) and include it several times for each product in a table. When tags and updated in this table, the database should be updates with the tags for that specific values.

The parent component:

```html
  (...)
  @for(int i=0;i<this.document.Count;i++)
                    {
                        DocumentModel p = this.document.ElementAt(i);
                        <tr>
                            <td><TagManagement @key=@p.id organizationId=@p.organizacao_id documentId=@p.id OnTagsChange="TagsHandler" /></td>
              
                        </tr>
                    }
(...)

void TagsHandler(Notification notification)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello"); //only for testing purposes
    
}
```

A two-way binding is implemented between the parent and child. However, o have no idea how to handle multiple component invocation with callback function for each one. When a new tag is inserted, only works on the first element of the table and the event is fired two times (because in this test I only have two rows).

I tried to include the key attribute but didn't work. Can you please help me?

Best regards

Comment: I see that you're trying to really explain things, but I'm pretty unclear still.  What, exactly, are you trying to do with JavaScript that you can't do in  Blazor?

Comment: Hi, like @bennyboy1973 I'm struggling to get my head around what's going on.  Can you simplify out your code into say a standalone component to demo your problem?